# Changing variable in function

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to make it when I press a button, a bunch of variables change.

```
function BuyItem(price, quantity, pps, text, quantitytext)
    if(PixoosQuantity >= price) then
        PixoosQuantity = PixoosQuantity - price
        price = price * 1.1

        quantity = quantity + 1

        PixoosPerSecond = PixoosPerSecond + pps
        PixoosPerSecondDisplay.text = "PPS: " .. string.format("%.3f", PixoosPerSecond)
        PixoosQuantityDisplay.text = "Pixoos: " .. string.format("%.3f", PixoosQuantity)

        text.text = "Deck of playing cards\nPrice: " .. string.format("%.3f", price) .. " Pixoos"
        quantitytext.text = quantity
    end
end
```

This is a function which gets called upon button press:

```
function ButtonAction(event)
    if event.target.name == "DeckOfPlayingCards" then
        BuyItem(DeckOfPlayingCardsPrice, DeckOfPlayingCardsQuantity, DeckOfPlayingCardsPPS, DeckOfPlayingCardsText, DeckOfPlayingCardsQuantityText)
    end
end
```

My question is, why don't the variables change? I tried putting `return price` and such, but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the variable `price` by value and not [by reference](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-06/msg00257.html). This construct does not exists in Lua, so you need to workaround it, for example by using the return value:

```
DeckOfPlayingCardsPrice, DeckOfPlayingCardsText, DeckOfPlayingCardsQuantityText = BuyItem(DeckOfPlayingCardsPrice, [...], DeckOfPlayingCardsText, DeckOfPlayingCardsQuantityText)
```

and return the expected value properly:

```
function BuyItem(price, quantity, pps, text, quantitytext)
    if(PixoosQuantity >= price) then
        [...]
    end
    return price, quantity, quantitytext
end
```

In Lua you can [return multiple results](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html).

Comment: Problem is that I need to change not only price, but also quantity, text and also quantitytext. How can I do all that in one function? Is is even possible?

Comment: In Lua you can return more values and assign them to appropriate variables. I modified the answer.